# Template tag for hiding sensitive user information in Django

Tags: django, templates

I'm trying to do this in a template:

```
  myacctspecial@gmail.com
  myaccxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to partially hide emails. Is there a template tag in Django that hides part of a string with x's?

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest** way is to prepare a `hidden_version` of user's email address in `views.py` and pass it to your template. **However**, If you want to do it in templates directly, django user doesn't have that sort of function by default. You can add a new method to `User` model. Create a file `user_patch.py` in your `app`:

```
#app/user_patch.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

def hide_email(self):
    # Return a hiding version of self.email

User.add_to_class("hide_email",hide_email)
```

and import it in app's `__init__.py` file using:

```
#app/__init__.py
import user_patch
```

And then you have an option in `template` files whether to render hidden version of the user's email address:

```
{{ user.hide_email }}
```